# Uploadify 3.0 file not upload all file queue if auto set to false

Tags: uploadify

If anyone facing this like i do, i set the auto to false and call the function from upload

$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();

i tried select more than 1 file, if i click the file_upload the file and selec, all the file is on queue. however after i click the button the only first file in queue upload, its wont auto fire / upload the second file in queue.

If i set the auto to true, it works like prefectly where all the file queue will be upload by sequence.

Any suggestion what i done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even I've the same problem . could not find any solution on Google. If you got rid of this please post as answer

Answer (score 4):

When `auto: false` you can upload all files in queue with below code.

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify('upload', '*');
```

To select multiple files you might want to set option `multi: true`

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the uploadify-min file and just prayed that I'd find an easy fix...

('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload("*");

There you go. This is a bit late for you, sorry :/, but I GUARANTEE someone else will find this useful. I haven't found any documentation or forum posts on the issue, so this should be a life saver.

It turns out that all auto really did is call the uploadify function instantly, but with an added asterisk parameter.

big edit:

What a horrible reply... well I was pretty shattered at the time of writing, so I'll sum it up more accurately.

I checked inside of the uploadify code in order to see how "auto" uploaded "them all in sequence", and found out that all that it was doing was adding an asterisk parameter to the bog standard uploadify command.

So with auto off, you can write ('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload("*");

And it will upload everything without auto... I think...

Answer (score 0):

That's what [auto](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/auto/) is for. If auto is not true, you need to listen for an event like [OnComplete](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/), and then you would upload the next file manually until the queue is empty.

It's a lot easier to just set auto to true.

Comment: thanks for the response, the reason set auto to false is i post the comment and the attachment together. i select the file(s) to upload and key in the comment and then click to upload. but each time click only trigger to upload the queue once. how to manually call from the script each time the file upload complete?

Answer (score 0):

if you use different version,
try

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify('upload', '*');
```

or

```
("#file_upload").uploadifyUpload("*");
```